# ArrayList not keeping added elements when it leaves method

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an android application where I call a method inside my onCreate, and in that method I add objects to my ArrayList. When the program leaves the method, all those added elements aren't saved and my arraylist size is 0. Can anyone tell me the problem?

```
 private ArrayList<EventInformation> eventArray = new ArrayList<EventInformation>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTV);

    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    final String ts = tsLong.toString();
    //String hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex

    String url = "";

    RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();

    JsonObjectRequest obj = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            parseJSONResponse(response); // where I call the method
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTV.setText(ts);

        }
    });

    queue.add(obj);

    for (int i = 0; i < eventArray.size(); i++) {
        mTV.append("Id: " + String.valueOf(eventArray.get(i).id) + '\n' +
                "Title: " + eventArray.get(i).title + '\n' +
                "Description: " + eventArray.get(i).description + '\n');
    }

    display();

}

public void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        JSONObject ar = response.getJSONObject("data");
        int total = ar.getInt("total");
        JSONArray arr = ar.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            JSONObject currentObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = currentObject.getInt("id");
            String title = currentObject.getString("title");
            String description = currentObject.getString("description");
            String resourceURI = currentObject.getString("resourceURI");
            EventInformation toAdd = new EventInformation(id, title, description, resourceURI);
            eventArray.add(toAdd); // successfully adds the object
            Log.i("tag", String.valueOf(eventArray.size())); //log shows size is 60+ here but after it leaves, it is 0
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {

    }
}
```

I also tried initializing the ArrayList inside my onCreate, and outside. Both have the same results

edit: logcat:

```
02-11 21:47:46.451      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 1
02-11 21:47:46.451      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 2
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 3
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 4
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 5
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 6
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 7
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 8
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 9
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 10
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 11
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 12
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 13
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 14
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 15
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 16
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 17
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 18
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 19
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 20
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 21
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 22
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 23
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 24
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 25
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 26
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 27
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 28
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 29
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 30
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 31
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 32
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 33
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 34
02-11 21:47:46.461      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 35
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 36
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 37
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 38
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 39
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 40
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 41
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 42
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 43
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 44
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 45
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 46
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 47
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 48
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 49
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 50
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 51
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 52
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 53
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 54
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 55
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 56
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 57
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 58
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 59
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 60
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 61
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 62
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 63
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 64
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 65
02-11 21:47:46.471      685-685/kim.albert.marveleventtracker I/tag﹕ 66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code won't wait for the response, rather it would execute straight way, I mean it will just execute the request to the server, mean time your time arrives, it will start execution of the below code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < eventArray.size(); i++) {
     mTV.append("Id: " + String.valueOf(eventArray.get(i).id) + '\n' +
              "Title: " + eventArray.get(i).title + '\n' +
             "Description: " + eventArray.get(i).description + '\n');
 }

 display();
```

So idea case is, there should be a condition which checks whether response has been received successfully!

OR

The best way is to create a method and call inside the `onResponse()` method.

Comment: If there was an if statement before the for loop, but the lines of code after the request is called anyways, wouldn't it just return false? Also what would the if statement be? Is there a way to wait for the request to finish before executing more lines of code?

Comment: @fredjones my meaning was to implement a condition code mechanism somewhere, based on the successful/error response arrives, it would start further execution!

Comment: could you give me an example of such a condition code, and where in the program to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the array before you add data to it.

Your JSON request code does not wait for the request to be completed. It says "Hey, start this request now, and when it finishes give the results back to me (and when the results come back to you, you call `parseJSONResponse` to add them to the list)".

In the mean time, while that request is going off to the server (networks are slow), you print the contents of the list.

When the response comes back, you add the elements to the list.

Comment: how can I call the method after the request finishes?

Comment: Call which method after the request finishes?

Comment: The parseJSONResponse. Or is there a way to wait for the request to finish before executing more lines of code?

Comment: Calling `parseJSONResponse` after the request finishes is something you already do. The library (not sure what it is exactly) calls the `void onResponse(JSONObject response)` method in your `ResponseListener` once it gets the response. And that method calls `parseJSONResponse`.